# Laravel pass a certain parameter to all routes in all views

Tags: php, laravel

I needed to pass a subdomain name to all views so that when they generate routes with `route('namedRoute')` users will end up in the same subdomain.

I ended up creating a `ViewServiceProvider` which registers a [view composer](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#view-composers) where I get the subdomain from the request like so:

```
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View as FView;
    use Illuminate\View\View;

    class ViewServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
         FView::composer('*', function(View $view){
             $view->with('subdomain', request()->route()->subdomain);
         });
    }
```

This way the subdomain variable will be passed to every singe view every time thanks to the `'*'` as documented in [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#view-composers).

Then when I need to generate any route in any view, I will always have to pass the subdomain like so and the route will be generated correctly.

```
    {{ route('signInPage', ['subdomain' => $subdomain]) }}
```

So is there something in laravel (like a `post view processing`) that I can hook into to populate the subdomain automatically so I don't have to now modify every route generation in every view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL generator can take defaults so you don't have to pass a paremeter for the route when generating the URL:

```
URL::defaults(['subdomain' => ....]);
```

You can create a route middleware that gets the `subdomain` parameter from the request and sets this default.

[Laravel 8.x Docs - URLs - Default Values](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/urls#default-values)

Comment: That sounds even better than what I did, I'll read about it, give it a try and see. Thanks!

Comment: no problem, if that example in the docs isn't enough I can provide you with some code, good luck :)

Comment: I only have a problem now that for some reason in the middleware where I'd call this URL::defaults, I'm getting null for `request()->route()`, so trying to find out if I did something wrong or how to get subdomain from url

Comment: this is being added as a route middleware not a global middleware? if you want to give me a link to a paste of what you have I can take a look at it ... also in the middleware you would just use `$request` since that is the Request instance

Comment: it is in the global middleware and I've tried $request()->route()->subdomain and it keeps saying "Trying to get property 'subdomain' of non-object"

Comment: i would make it a route middleware and apply it to what ever group the routes are in .. you can also use `$request->route('subdomain')` to attempt to retrieve the parameter ... also what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I ended up adding it into application's route middleware 'web' group so it'll get automatically applied to all routes defined in web.php

Comment: One problem: For some reason by introducing the same matching routes but without the subdomain parameter and try to access a subdomain route, then URL::defaults still sets the subdomain to the correct value, but the generated routes in the views have no subdomain.

Comment: It is probably because named routes must be unique. By introducing a new set of the same routes that should be distinguished by a parameter as opposed the route name, views will match the last route name added. So to fix that, I will need to generate a prefix for the subdomain routes and all views will have to be passed a variable with this prefix - either empty or populated and generate routes with the concatenated route name. To determine if the variable should contain the prefix or not, I can rely on the standard laravel routing and just see if the subdomain has been populated.